# Parent component rerender useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent Component named Posts that has a useEffect and fetches data, then I have a child component named Post which renders the post from props. I have a delete and like function inside Post and I want the parent to rerender when post get liked or post gets deleted. How can I achieve this?

```
const Posts = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  const getPosts = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://localhost:1111/api/posts/posts', {
      credentials: 'include'
    });
    const response = await data.json();
    console.log(response);
    setPosts(response);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(post => (
        <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Post = props => {
  const like = async post => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', post);
    const data = await fetch('https://localhost:1111/api/posts/like', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      credentials: 'include'
    });

    const response = await data.json();
    console.log(response);
  };

  const deletePost = async post => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', post);
    const data = await fetch('https://localhost:1111/api/posts/deletepost', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      credentials: 'include'
    });

    const response = await data.json();
    console.log(response);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={`http://localhost:1111/api/posts/uploads/images/${props.post.content}`}
        alt={`Post ${props.post.id}`}
      />
      <button onClick={() => like(props.post.id)}>Like</button>
      <button onClick={() => deletePost(props.post.id)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why would you want the parent Posts to re-render though? Isn't it sufficient that the child Post is re-rendered?

Comment: Because the parent Posts is the component that fetches the data, and I want to have live update on like and delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to have an additional prop method (`onUpdate`) on the child `<Post />` component, which gets triggered whenever the `deletePost()` or `like()` are triggered.

```
const Posts = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  const getPosts = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://localhost:1111/api/posts/posts', {
      credentials: 'include'
    });
    const response = await data.json();
    console.log(response);
    setPosts(response);
  };

 const handleUpdate = () => {
   getPosts();
 }

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(post => (
        <Post key={post.id} onUpdate={() => handleUpdate()} post={post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Post = props => {
  const { onUpdate } = props;

  const like = async post => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', post);
    const data = await fetch('https://localhost:1111/api/posts/like', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      credentials: 'include'
    });

    const response = await data.json();
    console.log(response);

    onUpdate();
  };

  const deletePost = async post => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', post);
    const data = await fetch('https://localhost:1111/api/posts/deletepost', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      credentials: 'include'
    });

    const response = await data.json();
    console.log(response);

    onUpdate();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={`http://localhost:1111/api/posts/uploads/images/${props.post.content}`}
        alt={`Post ${props.post.id}`}
      />
      <button onClick={() => like(props.post.id)}>Like</button>
      <button onClick={() => deletePost(props.post.id)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see, `onUpdate()` is called at the end of both `deletePost()` and `like()`, and on the parent Posts component, `handleUpdate()` will be called, which in turn submits the fetch response to update the `posts` state. This will cause the parent `<Posts />` to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Keep post functionality inside the parent component and pass the update functions to `Post`

```js
const Posts = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://localhost:1111/api/posts/posts', {
      credentials: 'include',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setPosts)
  }, [])

  const likePost = async postId => {
    await fetch...
    setPosts(prevState =>
      prevState.map(post =>
        post.id === postId
          ? {
              ...post,
              likes: post.likes + 1,
            }
          : post
      )
    )
  }

  const deletePost = async postId => {
    await fetch...
    setPosts(prevState => prevState.filter(post => post.id !== postId))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(post => (
        <Post
          key={post.id}
          post={post}
          likePost={likePost}
          deletePost={deletePost}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const Post = ({ post, likePost, deletePost }) => (
  <div>
    <img
      src={`http://localhost:1111/api/posts/uploads/images/${post.content}`}
      alt={`Post ${post.id}`}
    />
    <button onClick={() => likePost(post.id)}>Like</button>
    <button onClick={() => deletePost(post.id)}>Delete</button>
  </div>
)
```